# Xml validation against xml schema fails in php but works in .NET (VS2010)

Tags: php, xml, xsd, primary-key, keyref

I have several xml files, but I will present only one and the xsd against which I validate it. Let me describe the problem at first. I edit the files in VS2010 and the VS run time parser shows no errors while editting the xml file. Then when I run a php command line script which loads the xml file and validates it against the xml schema, it ends with an excption saying

> Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Element 'element': No match found for key-sequence ['answers'] of keyref 'elementRef'.

However, I really cannot see a mistake in the xsd file.

Xml file:

```
<domain xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="Answer" namespace="Custom\Surveys" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../xsd/domain.xsd">
    <entities>
        <entity name="Answer" main="true" schema="answers"/>
    </entities>
    <bindings>      
    </bindings>
    <key>
        <element entity="answers" property="question_option_id"/>
        <element entity="answers" property="survey_voter_id"/>
    </key>
</domain>
```

Xml schema in an xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
    <xs:element name="domain">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="entities">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="entity" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" id="entityName" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="main" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" default="false" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="schema" type="xs:string" use="required" id="schemaName" />                                  
                                </xs:complexType>                               
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="multientity" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="schema" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>                   
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="bindings" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="bind" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="referenced">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="entity" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                                <xs:attribute name="property" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:keyref name="referencedRef" refer="entityId">
                                                <xs:selector xpath="." />
                                                <xs:field xpath="@entity" />
                                            </xs:keyref>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="entity" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="property" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                                <xs:keyref name="bindRef" refer="entityId">
                                    <xs:selector xpath="." />
                                    <xs:field xpath="@entity" />
                                </xs:keyref>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="key">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="element" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="entity" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="property" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                                <xs:keyref name="elementRef" refer="entityId">
                                    <xs:selector xpath="." />
                                    <xs:field xpath="@entity" />
                                </xs:keyref>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>                   
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />            
            <xs:attribute name="namespace" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="entityId">
            <xs:selector xpath="./entities/entity|./entities/multientity" />
            <xs:field xpath="@schema" />
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: have you added the proper header to your XML file? `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, I had to define all the keys and keyrefs in the root element at the end.

Here goes the new xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
    <xs:element name="domain">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="entities">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="entity" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" id="entityName" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="main" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" default="false" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="schema" type="xs:string" use="required" id="schemaName" />                                  
                                </xs:complexType>                               
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="multientity" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="schema" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>                   
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="bindings" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="bind" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="referenced">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="entity" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                                <xs:attribute name="property" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                            </xs:complexType>                                           
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="entity" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="property" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:complexType>                               
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="key">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="element" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="entity" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                    <xs:attribute name="property" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>                   
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />            
            <xs:attribute name="namespace" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="entityId">
            <xs:selector xpath="./entities/entity|./entities/multientity" />
            <xs:field xpath="@schema" />
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="elementRef" refer="entityId">
            <xs:selector xpath="./key/element" />
            <xs:field xpath="@entity" />
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="bindRef" refer="entityId">
            <xs:selector xpath="./bindings/bind" />
            <xs:field xpath="@entity" />
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="referencedRef" refer="entityId">
            <xs:selector xpath="./bindings/bind/referenced" />
            <xs:field xpath="@entity" />
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend always putting a keyref and its corresponding key at the same level (in the same element declaration) if you possibly can. It's not required in theory, but the rules when you don't are incredibly complex and sometimes counter-intuitive. (The reason I'm not telling you what the rules are is that I know that reading the spec in this area hurts my brain, and I can't possibly remember the rules without reading the spec.)

Comment: I know I have tried to read the rules. I did exactly what you say (viz my own answer).